# How to webscrape and Extract table values from website

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is there a way to scrape all the coordinates from [here](http://www.imo.org/en/OurWork/Environment/PollutionPrevention/AirPollution/Pages/Emission-Control-Areas-%28ECAs%29-designated-under-regulation-13-of-MARPOL-Annex-VI-%28NOx-emission-control%29.aspx)?

I know that I must do something like:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

url <- "http://www.imo.org/en/OurWork/Environment/PollutionPrevention/AirPollution/Pages/Emission-Control-Areas-%28ECAs%29-designated-under-regulation-13-of-MARPOL-Annex-VI-%28NOx-emission-control%29.aspx"
page <- html(url)

coords <- page %>% html_nodes(".") %>% html_text()
```

But I am not sure how to find what to put in html_nodes.

I am trying to run the firebug  in order to find out but it's a mess (I don't have any experience though to web scrape or using firebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different approach:

```
library(sp)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)

target_url <- "http://www.imo.org/en/OurWork/Environment/PollutionPrevention/AirPollution/Pages/Emission-Control-Areas-%28ECAs%29-designated-under-regulation-13-of-MARPOL-Annex-VI-%28NOx-emission-control%29.aspx"

pg <- read_html(target_url)
```

Now that we have the page we'll need to get the proper elements, but the coordinates are in a format that makes it hard to use so we'll convert them as we go, using a helper function:

```
dms_to_dec <- function(x) {

  html_text(x) %>% 
    stri_replace_first_regex("º ", "d") %>% 
    stri_replace_first_regex("′ ", "'") %>% 
    stri_replace_first_regex("″", "") %>% 
    stri_replace_all_regex("[ \\.]", "") %>% 
    char2dms() %>% 
    as.numeric.DMS()

}
```

Now, we target each table, but pull out the individual data elements that are *insanely* stored (each) in a single `<td>` wrapped (each) in `<p>` tags. We'll yank them out and then make a single data frame, using the table # as a column group.

```
html_nodes(pg, "table.ms-rteTable-default") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    data_frame(
      point = html_nodes(.x, xpath=".//td[1]/p") %>% xml_double(),
      latitude = html_nodes(.x, xpath=".//td[2]/p") %>% dms_to_dec(),
      longitude = html_nodes(.x, xpath=".//td[3]/p") %>% dms_to_dec()
    )
  }, .id = "table_num") -> regions
```

Let's take a look:

```
group_by(regions, table_num) %>% 
  summarise(n_points = n())
## # A tibble: 8 x 2
##   table_num n_points
##       <chr>    <int>
## 1         1       47
## 2         2      206
## 3         3       45
## 4         4       55
## 5         5       47
## 6         6      206
## 7         7       45
## 8         8       55
```

And, an even better "look":

```
ggplot(regions, aes(longitude, latitude, group=table_num)) + 
  geom_path(aes(color=table_num)) +
  ggthemes::scale_color_tableau() +
  coord_map("polyconic") +
  theme_ipsum_rc(grid="XY")
```

[image]

Looks abt right, too:

```
library(rgdal)

usa <- readOGR("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_outline_500k.json")
usa_map <- fortify(subset(usa, R_STATEFP != "02" & L_STATEFP != "02"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data=usa_map, map=usa_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id), color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill="white") +
  geom_path(data=regions, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, group=table_num, color=table_num)) +
  ggthemes::scale_color_tableau() +
  coord_map(xlim=c(-180, -47)) +
  theme_ipsum_rc(grid="XY")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!Very nice!(upv)

Answer (score 1):

The tables on the page are poorly structured, and rather than having rows for each datapoint, there is one row for the headers, and one row for all of the data with each datapoint being separated as a new paragraph. The following code should work to convert this data into a list of dataframes.

```
library(rvest)

# Set URL
url <- "http://www.imo.org/en/OurWork/Environment/PollutionPrevention/AirPollution/Pages/Emission-Control-Areas-%28ECAs%29-designated-under-regulation-13-of-MARPOL-Annex-VI-%28NOx-emission-control%29.aspx"

# Get webpage
webpage <- read_html(url)

# Create empty list to hold dataframes
ldf <- list()

# Get list of tables
tables <- webpage %>%
          html_nodes("table.ms-rteTable-default") 

# Loop through tables
for(t in 1:length(tables)){
  # Get table data
  table.data <- tables[[t]] %>%
                html_nodes("td")

  # Extract points from table.data
  points <- table.data[4] %>%
            html_nodes("p") %>%
            html_text()

  # Extract latitudes from table.data
  lats <- table.data[5] %>%
          html_nodes("p") %>%
          html_text() %>%
          sub(pattern = "″", replacement = "\"")

  # Extract longitudes from table.data
  lons <- table.data[6] %>%
          html_nodes("p") %>%
          html_text() %>%
          sub(pattern = "″", replacement = "\"")

  # Add dataframe to the list
  ldf[[t]] <- data.frame(Point = points, Latitude = lats, Longitude = lons, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# Print list of dataframes
ldf
```

Comment: I've modified my answer to simplify how it works and retrieve all tables more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

html_nodes("table.ms-rteTable-default") %>% html_table()

Comment: Hmm,thanks.I can't understand if it catches all the values of the page.Any idea how to clean them and put them in a table/dataframe?

Comment: html_table() is not doing the job well, but it was him the one supposed to do that.
You can always extract the 3 columns that you are looking for and then create the data.frame.

Comment: it is extracting all the values on the page. I'm catching all tables with the class .ms-rteTable-default.